# How to get rid of RSS link in Hugo template?

Tags: rss, hugo

I'd like to get rid of the default [rss](/questions/tagged/rss) feed link that appears in my website's main menu. I was able to delete the default `Archives` link by deleting the corresponding code under `[[menu.main]]` in `config.toml`, but no similar code block exists for [rss](/questions/tagged/rss). I also tried going into `index.html` and deleting lines that appeared to correspond to [rss](/questions/tagged/rss) to no avail. I'm using blogdown and the Hugo template [Noteworthy](https://github.com/kimcc/hugo-theme-noteworthy) to build my site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove the RSS link from the menu in the Noteworthy theme, remove line 8 from the file `/layouts/partials/nav.html`. The line should look like this:

```html
  <a class="color-link nav-link" href="{{ .Site.RSSLink }}" target="_blank" rel="noopener" type="application/rss+xml">RSS</a>
```

As you can see, the RSS link was hardcoded into the template, so it would not be possible to remove it by editing the menu in `config.toml`.

Edit: The full location of the file will probably be `themes/noteworthy/layouts/partials/nav.html`.